# Why isn’t spin a magnetic charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin

It is often said that an electron’s spin generates a magnetic field even when stationary. The second Maxwell’s equation tells us that $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$ implying that there are no magnetic charges. This means that if a particle is at rest, it must have a magnetic field with 0 divergence. However, this leads to a contradiction since electrons have no magnetic charge yet still have a magnetic field with nonzero divergence when stationary. So why don’t we say that the electron just has a magnetic charge? Why do we have to introduce spin to this?

Comment: I don't understand this question: The electron's behaviour is not that of a magnetic monopole, so why would you want to say it has a magnetic charge? Also, how would a "magnetic charge" explain things like the Stern-Gerlach experiments?

Comment: The electron has a magnetic field with nonzero divergence like a magnetic monopole, no?

Comment: No, why would it? It has a *magnetic dipole moment*, it's not a monopole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, this leads to a contradiction since electrons have no magnetic charge yet still have a magnetic field with nonzero divergence when stationary.

This is incorrect. The electron has a magnetic dipole moment, not a magnetic monopole moment. So the corresponding field has zero divergence everywhere.

> So why don’t we say that the electron just has a magnetic charge?

Because it doesn’t. A magnetic charge would imply a monopole moment, not a dipole.

> Why do we have to introduce spin to this?

In addition to the above, uncharged fundamental particles also have spin but will not have a magnetic dipole moment. So you cannot avoid spin with uncharged particles, and you cannot equate spin with a magnetic charge for charged particles.

Comment: Dale, we give the uncharged neutron a spin. This is experimentally so because the neutron has a magnetic dipole and is reflected when moving non-parallel through a magnetic field. The hair-pulling decomposition of the neutron does not matter at all to the experimenter. For him, the following applies: magnetic dipole in the magnetic field -> lateral deflection -> spin.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler a neutron is not a fundamental particle

Comment: I‘m aware of this construct. Because after getting the magnetic dipole moment of the neutron the chain „charge - spin“ chrashes and it was needed or to say uncharged particle can have a spin or introduce the neutron composition. We know, how it is interpreted in todays days. In German we say, think over the edge of your plate ;-)

Comment: @HolgerFiedler the issue isn’t that some uncharged particles have spin and a magnetic moment. The issue is that some uncharged particles have spin and do not have a magnetic moment. So you cannot replace the concept of spin with the concept of a magnetic charge as the OP wanted

Comment: Dale, which particles?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler photons have spin but no magnetic moment, so that is the main issue with trying to replace the concept of spin with magnetic moment. Also, to my knowledge we have only upper bounds but not lower bounds for the magnetic moment of neutrinos and Z bosons, although that could certainly have changed recently. So even in these particles certainly the spin is much easier to detect than the magnetic moment so it wouldn't make sense to replace an easily detectable quantity with a poorly known one